# Получаю дубликат класса в HERE sdk

Tags: android, sdk

Пытаюсь подружить приложение с HERE sdk, но конфликт внутри самой библиотеки. Вот логи:`Duplicate class com.nokia.maps.z4 found in modules jetified-HERE-sdk-runtime.jar (:HERE-sdk:) and jetified-HERE-sdk-runtime.jar (HERE-sdk.aar)`

Что с этим чудом делать, и делать ли вообще ? Мне нужно голосовой помощник навигации установить в приложение, может еще какие то варианты есть?

Comment: Не знаю про варианты, но конкретно эту библиотеку вы подключили дважды - судя по всему один раз как модуль `(:HERE-sdk:)`, второй как AAR-файл `(HERE-sdk.aar)`

Comment: Та нет, один файл, один путь. Мало того... создал отдельный проект, полностью пустой, чисто под эту библиотеку, и та же ошибка ...